# Take input from mobile in matlab

Tags: matlab, mobile

I am making a project and in that i want to take input from mobile to matlab on computer. Plz someone help me with this. At-least tell me if can be happen or not or is there any alternate way to do so. I am using an Android phone Samsung Note-2.

Comment: What kind of mobile phone are you using? Please provide more info in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this a long time ago. If you are looking for a cheap (read free) way of doing it, I have good news for you. There are two I tried and they worked but not very satisfactorily.

1. Mobile => SMS => FACEBOOK => PC

   You might be aware of the facebook option to send messages through mobile itself. You need to activate the mobile notification option and then you will receive new messages as sms's in your mobile. There is an option to reply.

   - Send a message from facebook to yourself. You'll get the notification.
   - Use LIBCURL and write a code to monitor the conversation thread (with yourself in facebook) from PC. You need to create an App in facebook and authenticate it to access your inbox. There are technicalities like OAuth and other things. There are a lot of examples online.
   - Just type the matlab command and your script should save that command to a file. This file should be monitored by matlab and must execute the command. The output of the command is stored in another file and this file is accessed by the libcurl script and it sends it your mobile through one of the many sites (FullOnSms.com). Again you need to use libcurl to post to the specific form in the sms website.

   **PROS**: Cheapest.

   **CON**:  Heavy code and maintaining the code is a problem since the websites keep changing.
        Sometimes the facebook sms thing is late and your replies are late.
2. Dropbox => Matlab

   This is so much simpler but you need gprs in your mobile to access dropbox. Type the command in the dropbox file. Matlab in your PC monitors the file and pulls the last line and runs it in the console. Output is written (appended) to the same file which gets updated quickly in your mobile. 
   Your file becomes the command line essentially.

   **PROS**: Best method I could come up with and it worked like a charm.

   **CONS**: Not so cheap. You need to pay for GPRS.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to MATLAB remotely from your Android smartphone or tablet using this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathworks.matlabmobile